# Does Christianity StackExchange have enough answers to start a dogma creed?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of good answers and some bad ones. But has this site raised enough awareness to society of what is the truth.

Has it gotten the attention of Time's man of the year, and top Dogma leader, Pope Francis.

Or it doesn't matter that some users have 100k reputation here and we just have an opinion of the bible.

The bible, Dogma, and the Nicene Creed have already been established yet we look here for answers, why?

Basically, is there any proof that the Media has cover this site? Or are we like unmarked graves?

Luke 11:44
“Woe to you, because you are like unmarked graves, which people walk over without knowing it.”

thanks for reading

Comment: I learned a lot of things here, even thing which I have never heard before, and I think that some people here provide an excellent service, but the Holy Father decided to give His word to Twitter, though.

Comment: This misunderstands the site, which answers technical questions on the doctrine of Christianity as expressed by different Churches. The site categorically does not set out to say which of those doctrines is correct.

Comment: @Andrew, as always I agree with you, but in this case, if I were been you I would have ended the comment adding at the very end, after 'correct', 'if there is one.' ('... which of those doctrines is correct, *if there is one*.')

Comment: Why would the media look to this site? In what way Christianity Stack supposed to be "unmarked graves"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There are a lot of good answers and some bad ones.

Though the number of votes determine the quality of an answer, it doesn't always mean it is TRUE or it is the TRUTH. It simply means that the other users here like it and voted it up. Bad answers are mostly voted down or deleted. As the number of users increased, this site needs more high rep users to handle it. I don't think we have sufficient high rep users to handle each and every posts here. Any one can contribute and sacrifice their time on this site, and you can be that person.

> But has this site raised enough awareness to society of what is the
>   truth.

This site is not that popular yet. Searching about theology on Google doesn't return the posts from this site on the first page, which means that there are other more popular sites than this one. Moreover, this site policy doesn't allow Truth related questions and answers. Their is no propaganda here. Hence, it is very safe.

> The bible, Dogma, and the Nicene Creed have already been established
>   yet we look here for answers, why?

No one knows everything. A protestant doesn't know the details about the Catholic Church and it's practices. We are here to share our knowledge. We are here to learn from others and let others learn from us.